# property 'start' undefined vuejs laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

im trying to learn vuejs+laravel but i found error like this

and i can figure it out

[image: errror]

i want to creat simple crud, and now i want to store data..

this is the component users.vue

[image: errror]

and the app.js

[image: errror]

thanks before

Comment: Please post code and error messages as text rather than images. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Where is `this.$Progress` defined?